# How to adapt a table with fixed header and left column to window size?

Tags: css, html-table

I have a CSS file to lock the header and column of a html table, but if I try to adapt the outer frame to window size, the locking function is lost. How can I overcome this problem?

This is part of my CSS:

```
body, html, table {
...
}

table {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffd699; /* First column, same as first header cell */
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


/*thead*/
thead {
  position: relative;
  display: block; /* Separates the header from the body allowing it to be positioned*/
  width: 1600px; /* Total scrollable header width, same as tbody width */
  overflow: visible;
}

thead th {
...
}

thead th:nth-child(1) {/*The first cell in the header*/
  position: relative;
  display: block; /* Separates the first cell in the header from the header*/
...
}

thead tr th:nth-child(1) {  /* The first header cell in each tr*/
  position: relative;
  display: block; /* Separates the first column from the thead*/
...
}

/*tbody*/
tbody {
  position: relative;
  display: block; /* Separates the tbody from the header*/
  width: 1600px; /* Total scrollable tbody width, same as header width */
  height: 800px;  /* Total scrollable tbody height */
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid white;
} 

tbody td { /* Table cells */
...
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {  /*The first cell in each tr*/
  position: relative;
  display: block; /* Separates the first column from the tbody*/
...
  border-top: 0px solid white;
}
```

The ... parts are excluded.
I inserted width:window.innerWidth and height:window.innerHeight in the code, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the URL you have shared [MTL_Istaby.html](https://listersharad.se/wp-content/uploads/documents/mantal/MTL_Istaby.html)

This jQuery code can help you, either `window.innerWidth` or `100%`

window.innerWidth

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('table').css('width', window.innerWidth - 25 + "px");
   $('table').css('display', 'block')
   
   $( window ).on( "resize", function() {
      $('table').css('width', window.innerWidth - 25 + "px");
   });

})
```

100%

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('table').css('width', "100%");
   $('table').css('display', 'block')
})
```

Also you try css `100%` width for the table and `display: block` which will auto occupy the width of the browser

```
table {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffd699; /* First column, same as first header cell */
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: block;
  width: 100%
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, but it does not help. I aim at a header that stays vertically fixed but moves horizontally with the columns, and a left column that stays horizontally fixed but moves with the rows. Example: https://listersharad.se/wp-content/uploads/documents/mantal/MTL_Istaby.html where everything works but the problem is that the outer frame cannot be adapted to window.innerWidth /-Height parameters without losing the fixed rows/columns.

Comment: The function is controlled by a script in the html file:
`<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('tbody').scroll(function(e) { //detect a scroll event on the tbody
$('thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the thead relative to the body scrolling
$('thead th:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first cell of the header
$('tbody td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first column of tdbody
  });
});
</script> 
`

Comment: you can dynamically set the outer frame with via javascript, I think that will solve the problem `$('table').css('width', window.innerWidth + "px")`

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid I would need help with that, too... :-(

Comment: provided an answer, if you want to test this with window resize, then you need to do more coding

Comment: Brilliant, Dickens,  thanks a lot!
I just had to reduce some px to be sure to remain inside the window, and to create space for the fixed header rows.